# Three.js - Changing color of a face from an imported mesh?

Tags: canvas, 3d, webgl, three.js

In three.js, I can't seem to find out how to target/change the color of a mesh imported from Blender. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Additionally, it would also be great to know how to get said face (or a face from any mesh for that matter) to 'overlap' or appear first over all other faces.

```
        loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        var callbackDice   = function( geometry ) { createMesh(geometry); };
        loader.load( "js/untitled.js", callbackDice );

function createMesh(geometry){
        material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material);
        mesh.scale.set( 75, 75, 75 );
        mesh.position.x = -1;
        scene.add( mesh);
    }
```

This is how I insert the mesh I need into the scene. I would like to target a specific face and change its color, but I have no idea how to do it because it is not an instance of the THREE object.

Comment: it would be best to give a little more context for your problem because now it is hard to understand what you want exactly.

Comment: @Gero3 Sorry mate, updated it a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`THREE.Mesh` actually is also `THREE.Object3D`. However I don't think that directly helps you.

I quite the [Updates wiki page](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates):

> You can change freely material used for geometry chunk, you cannot change how object is divided into chunks (according to face materials).
>
> If you need to have different configurations of materials during runtime, if number of materials / chunks is small, you could pre-divide object beforehand (e.g. hair / face / body / upper clothes / trousers for human, front / sides / top / glass / tire / interior for car).
>
> If number is large (e.g. each face could be potentially different), consider different solution, using attributes / textures to drive different per-face look.

Extrapolating from that, either use own material for each of the selectable faces (so you can change it upon picking) or write a custom solution that could dynamically color the relevant part of a texture or use custom attribute buffers to communicate the colored face.

One other option I can think of is to bake the colors in vertex colors and use those. Though you probably get color interpolation then and still need to make sure the modified buffer gets uploaded to the GPU.

As far as that "bringing one face to front" is concerned, I don't quite understand what you want. Do you wish to "explode" the face from the mesh, rotate it to face the camera or make sure the faces are in correct depth order?